# how to use dependency injection with repository in mix mode

Tags: c#, .net, oop, dependency-injection

i have the problem to use dependency injection in mix mode, mean one repository functions call in 2nd repository using inheritance, but i am not sure what i am mixing or what is wrong,

> 1. `ISmallBizRepository` `interface`

```
public interface ISmallBizRepository
{
    #region Clients
    bool Insert(ClientsDM obj);
    bool Update(ClientsDM original, ClientsDM updated);
    ClientsDM GetClientsByPrimaryKey(Guid id);
    IQueryable GetClients(Guid id, Guid firmid);
    IQueryable GetClients(Guid firmid);
    bool DeleteClients(Guid id, Guid deletedby);
    #endregion
}
```

> 2. `SmallBizRepository` `class`

```
public  class SmallBizRepository : BaseQueryHelper,ISmallBizRepository
{
   private SmallBizDbContext _ctx;
   public SmallBizRepository(SmallBizDbContext ctx)
   {
        _ctx = ctx;
   }
   public SmallBizRepository(IQueryHelperRepository repo)
        : base(repo)
   {
   }
   #region Clients
    public IQueryable GetClients(Guid firmid)
    {
        return TheRepository.GetClient(firmid);
    }
    #endregion
}
```

> 3. `BaseQueryHelper` `class`

```
public class BaseQueryHelper
{
    private IQueryHelperRepository _repo;
    public BaseQueryHelper(IQueryHelperRepository repo)
    {
        _repo = repo;
    }

    protected IQueryHelperRepository TheRepository
    {
        get
        {
            return _repo;
        }
    }
}
```

> 4. `IQueryHelperRepository` `interface`

```
public interface IQueryHelperRepository
{
    #region Firm
    IQueryable GetClient(Guid firmid);
    IQueryable GetClient(Guid firmid, Guid id);
    #endregion
}
```

> 5. `QueryHelperRepository` `class`

```
   public class QueryHelperRepository : IQueryHelperRepository
   {
    private SmallBizDbContext _ctx;
    public QueryHelperRepository(SmallBizDbContext ctx)
    {
        _ctx = ctx;
    }
    #region Firm
    public IQueryable GetClient(Guid firmid)
    {
        var Clientjc = from a in _ctx.Client
                       join b in _ctx.AflAwmAddrBook on a.AddressBookId equals b.AddressBookId into ab
                       from b1 in ab.DefaultIfEmpty()
                       where (a.DeletedOn == null && a.FirmId == firmid)
                       orderby a.CreatedDate descending
                       select new
                       {
                           a.FirmId,
                           a.ClientId,
                           a.FirstName,
                           a.LastName,
                           a.Email,
                           a.Phone,
                           a.Address,
                           a.City,
                           a.ZipCode,
                           a.State,
                           a.Country,
                           a.UserId,
                           a.PayPalEmail,
                           a.EmailApprovedDate,
                           a.IsApproved,
                           a.DeletedBy,
                           a.DeletedOn,
                           a.CreatedDate,
                           a.AddressBookId,
                           AflAwmAddrBook_fullname = b1.fullname,
                           a.Picture,
                       };

        return Clientjc;
    }
    #endregion
    }
```

> 6. `BaseApiController` `class`

```
    public class BaseApiController : ApiController
    {
    private ISmallBizRepository _repo;
    private ModelFactory _modelFactory;

    public BaseApiController(ISmallBizRepository repo)
    {
        _repo = repo;
    }

    protected ModelFactory TheModelFactory
    {
        get
        {
            if (_modelFactory == null)
            {
                _modelFactory = new ModelFactory(Request, TheRepository);
            }
            return _modelFactory;
        }
    }

    protected ISmallBizRepository TheRepository
    {
        get
        {
            return _repo;
        }
    }
}
```

the above repository classes working separately, but when we Inherit `QueryHelperRepository` with `SmallBizRepository` and use function like this

```
    #region Clients
    public IQueryable GetClients(Guid firmid)
    {
        return TheRepository.GetClient(firmid);
    }
    #endregion
```

in `SmallBizRepository`.

please help/guide me in this problem, i appreciate your valuable time.thanks in advance.

Comment: But what exactly is your problem? You just pasted a bunch of code. From the DI Frameworks I've worked with, Ninject is the one with most descriptive and helpful errors. We cannot help you if you don't tell us what's your problem.

Comment: basically, my problem is i have 2 different repositories, both are working independently, but i need to use QueryHelperRepository within SmallBizRepository, but the problem is both repositories have different contructors, i have the problem to use SmallBizRepository Contructor and QueryHelperRepository but we can use only one base class contructor, please help me, if you understand, i will explain more. thanks

Comment: @mnwsmit answer resolved my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On your SmallBizRepository you should have one constructor with both dependencies like this:

```
public class SmallBizRepository : BaseQueryHelper, ISmallBizRepository
{
    private SmallBizDbContext _ctx;
    public SmallBizRepository(SmallBizDbContext ctx, IQueryHelperRepository repo)
         : base(repo)
    {
        _ctx = ctx;
    }
    #region Clients
    public IQueryable GetClients(Guid firmid)
    {
        return TheRepository.GetClient(firmid);
    }
    #endregion
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. its  resolved my problem. thanks again